# Why $\|\frac{1}{2}(\|h\|+h)\|\leq\|h\|$?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Consider $h\in B(H)$, $h=h_1-h_2$, where $h_1=\frac{1}{2}(\|h\|+h)$ and $h_2=\frac{1}{2}(\|h\|-h)$.

In a proof of a theorem about positive elements of $C^*$-algebra, I see that $\|h_1\|\leq\|h\|$ and $\|h_2\|\leq\|h\|$. How?

I know that $h\leq h_1,h_2$, easy. But I tried proof $\|h_1\|\leq\|h\|$, my attempted (fail):

Let $x\in H$
$$
|\left \langle h_1x,x \right \rangle|=|\left \langle (h_1-h_2)x,x \right \rangle+\left \langle h_2x,x \right \rangle|
$$
when $\left \langle (h_1-h_2)x,x \right \rangle\leq0$ it's ok, but otherwise we have
$$
|\left \langle h_1x,x \right \rangle|>|\left \langle hx,x \right \rangle|
$$
So, what I do?

Comment: $\lVert h_1 \rVert \leq \tfrac{1}{2}\lVert \lVert h\rVert \rVert + \tfrac{1}{2}\lVert h \rVert = \lVert h \rVert$ - triangle inequality

Comment: for god sake, thanks